# savon gem example_body not coming properly

Tags: ruby, web-services, savon

I have a wsdl url to give request and get response this is my code(using savon gem for this)

```
client = Savon.new('http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7a?wsdl')
service = :Description7a
port = :Description7aPort
operation = :getDivisions
division = client.operation(service, port, operation)
```

I am able to print example_body like 
division.example_body

```
 => {:DivisionsRequest=>{:accountInfo=>{:_number=>"string", :_secret=>"string", :_country=>"string", :_language=>"string", :_behalfOf=>"string"}, :_modelYear=>"int"}}
```

and i'm able to set values like
     division.body = {.........}

other operation such like

```
operationlist = client.operations(service, port)
=> ["getVersionInfo", "getModelYears", "getDivisions", "getSubdivisions", "getModels", "getStyles", "describeVehicle", "getCategoryDefinitions", "getTechnicalSpecificationDefinitions"]
```

I used describe vehicle

```
desc_veh = client.operation(service, port, "describeVehicle")
```

whose example_body is like

```
desc_veh.example_body
=> {:VehicleDescriptionRequest=>{}}
```

so unable to set values for desc_veh.body and the use the .call function

I don know whether it is a savon gem problem or the wsdl url problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look like this:

```
gem "savon", "~> 2.0"
require "savon"
client = Savon.client(
    :wsdl => 'http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7a?wsdl',
    :convert_request_keys_to => :camelcase,
    :log => true,
    :log_level => :debug,
    :pretty_print_xml => true
)

res = client.call(:get_divisions,
    message: { :param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2' }
)

print res.to_hash
```

The parameters are simply a hash in key/value pairs.